# Keyword Searching

Tags: php, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split a list with multiple delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051402/how-can-i-split-a-list-with-multiple-delimiters)

I am a newbie in php and My client want me to search utility in php webapplication  using which  user can enter words having spaces or commas. I am not sure is this possible in php to seaparate a string based on commas and spaces as well. As explode converts the string in array which can not be again used with explode..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more complex string splitting, use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) or [`mb_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php) and supply a regular expression.

Use `mb_split()` if your input string is in a multibyte encoding and you need to match against those characters for your split expression.

Example:

```
$input = "a,b, c d";
$psplit = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $input);
$mbsplit = mb_split('[\s,]+', $input);
$psplit===$mbsplit; // === array('a','b','c','d');
```